# My login page looks very "weird" and big when strectching it

Tags: html, css, authentication, frontend

It should look like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Sq1D.png) but it instead looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHBiV.png).

Here's my HTML Code:

```css
/* Path: main.css */

@font-face {
  font-family: kardia;
  src: url(kardiathickrunner.ttf);
}

.square {
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 60vw;
  max-width: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  /* leave margin */
  margin: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">

  <button class="googlebutton">⠀ Login with Google </button>
  <p class="Login">Login</p>
</div>
```

I'm new to html and im trying to learn, so i'm really confused, because all of my other projects looks just fine, idk what could be happening. I need some help, sorry. This is the code refering to the div, that creates the white menu in the center.

Comment: you are trying to absolute position  your element but you are just compicating things. For how the DOM is built it is just a matter of putting things one after the other.

Comment: What styling have you given .google button and .Login? And are you allowed to alter the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

vw stands for viewport-width it is mainly used for width not height

Change the "vw" to "vh" for the property height in .square class making it to "vh" will achieve the layout you want.

I think using vw was not intentional if not please let me know why it was used.

Comment: There may be a good reason for using the same units for width and height, similar to setting the aspect-ratio.

Comment: Edited the answer according to the review comments.